# How to know the age of an android device?

Tags: android

Is there a way to know when the device booted for the first time?
I tried for the packageInfo.firstInstallTime, but its giving me wrong date(other than sGINGER_RELEASE_DATE).

Comment: Date which i received on Vivo 1716 device(android 7.1.2) is 2008-12-31, which is clearly not possible.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9242307/android-device-age

Comment: @NileshRathod I have followed the same answer.

Comment: @pskink I can't tell you exactly. For some of the devices i get correct date. While development i never got wrong dates.